# Rails 4: partial w/ locals works in one place but not another...why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

How to fix?

Renders jobs properly...

```
<% # jobs/_job.html.erb %>
<% # jobs/index.html.erb %>
<% # @jobs set in jobs#index %>

<%= render partial: 'jobs/job', locals: { jobs: @jobs } %>
```

Renders nothing...

```
<% # users/show.html.erb %>
<% # @jobs set in users#show %>
<% # binding.pry shows @jobs is set %>
<% # binding.pry shows local jobs is set %>

<%= # render partial: 'jobs/job', locals: { jobs: @jobs } %>
<% # adding the following line per @ suggestion, but still not rendering %>
<%= render partial: 'jobs/job', object: @jobs %>
```

**Edit:**

```
<% # _job.html.erb %>
<% @jobs.each do |job| %>
<% # stuff %>
<% end %>
```

**Pretty straight-forward, but just in case...**

```
# users_controller.rb
def show
  @pups           = current_user.pups
  @availabilities = current_user.availabilities
  @jobs           = current_user.jobs
end
```

Comment: Are there any errors?

Comment: In `users@show`, `@jobs` may be set, but is it a valid Job? Or is it blank?

Comment: @WesFosterr: valid jobs (jobs render as expected in jobs index.html.erb, nothing renders in users show.html.erb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**_job is supposed to only render the HTML view for a single job instance**

Be careful when you render partials with `render partial:`

For a partial defined in `views/object_name/_partial_name.html.erb`, the variable name `partial_name` is special, as it is considered to be the main object concerned by the view.

In other words

**jobs/_job.html.erb**

```
<% do_something_with(job) 
# NOT @job nor @jobs nor jobs
# The partial name is _job.html.erb => use the variable `job`
%>
```

When calling this partial you should use the `object` parameter (for a single instance) or `collection` to render an array of those objects

**users/show.html.erb**

```
<%= render partial: 'jobs/job', collection: @jobs
# This is going to render the partial as many times as there are job in @jobs
%>
```

See explanation + examples [in the doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials)

> Every partial also has a local variable with the same name as the partial (minus the underscore). You can pass an object in to this local variable via the :object option:

In a nutshell, the following options would work (scroll more on the doc for an explanation for the 3rd and 4th one)

**users/show.html.erb**

```
<%= @jobs.each do |job|
  render 'jobs/job', locals: { job: job } 
%>
OR
<%= @jobs.each do |job|
  render partial: `jobs/job`, object: job 
%>
OR
<%= render partial: `jobs/job`, collection: @jobs %>
OR
<%= render @jobs %>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Edited my code and question to reflect your suggestion, but still not seeing anything in users show.html.erb

Comment: You are not supposed to use `@jobs` but `job` in your partial `_job.html.erb`. I edit my post to clarify

Comment: Also, _job is supposed to only render the HTML view for a single job instance. You can have a look at `Spacer Templates` and `Collection Partial Layouts` if you need to do more complex stuff (in the link I gave)

Comment: Your last comment is the answer (close enough). I am trying to render multiple instances of the job object using a partial and that's apparently making the situation more confusing than it needs to be. Edited and accepted. Thanks.

Comment: Cool, glad I could help. I also made one last edit myself to fix a bad piece of code ^^"